# MailChip API V1.3 - Calling Templates() Returns NULL

Tags: mailchimp

I'm doing some work with the MailChimp API, so far I have managed to get a list of mailing lists VIA the api, but when I call the API method

```
//Assembly MailChimp.dll, v1.3.1.3

public Template.Templates Templates()
    {}
```

The API is returning NULL, when I call the method I am not passing any prams as I want to get all the templates in the account.

Any ideas why I would be getting null, is there something I need to do in mail chimp?

Comment: I added a new template via the API and now when I call the Templates method I get the one I added back... Great - But how come I don't get the others.. must be a setting in Mail Chimp... any ideas.. anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer....

When You create a template in Mail Chimp you have three options 1. basic, 2. Themes or 3.Code your own.

All templates that have been created with the 'Code your own option' will be returned by the API (V1.3)

I'm not sure why the other templates don't get returned, but I have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to send the `types` parameter to specify that you want to receive gallery or base templates. See [the docs on the v1.3 templates call](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/templates.func.php).